# unable to specify path to javascript file in Karma

Tags: karma-runner, karma-jasmine

My JS file (which I need to test) is /JasmineTest/src/mySource.js. It has `myObj` object

```
myObj={
    setA:function(value){
        a=value;
    },
    getA:function(){
        return a;
    },
};
```

My Jasmine spec file is /JasmineTest/spec/mySpec.js. It tests `myObj`

```
describe("Jasmine sample suite",function(){
    it("tracks that spy was called",function(){
        expect(myObj.getA).toHaveBeenCalled();
    });
```

In karma, I have specified the spec file location as

```
files: [
        'spec/*.js'
    ],
```

when I start Karma in /JasmineTest, the test gives error

```
Chrome 60.0.3112 (Windows 10 0.0.0) Jasmine sample suite tracks that spy was called FAILED
        ReferenceError: myObj is not defined
            at UserContext.<anonymous> (spec/mySpec.js:4:9)
```

I tried exporting myObj `module.exports = myObj;` and importing it in spec file using `require('../src/mySource.js')` but I got error `require is not defined`

How do I make myObj visible in the specs file?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Karma doesn't know how to do module requiring unless you configure it specially to do bundling. In general I would expect to use the same sort of bundling in Karma as you do for your web app, so Webpack or Browserify or similar.

Another way is to list mySource.js in under the "files" field in karma.conf.js, which will just execute it and put myObj in as a global, but that doesn't scale very well.

Comment: I don't know how to use webpack etc. so tried the 2nd approach.